# Campos sumindo no ionic após selecionar uma opocao do select

Tags: ionic, angular

Estou implementando uma funcionalidade onde o usuário seleciona uma opção do `select` e é enviado pra uma função que adiciona no meu model.

Por algum motivo, após selecionar a opção do meu `select`, o campo seguinte do meu `ngfor` some, ele reaparece se eu clicar em cima, tudo funciona normal no ionic serve, mas quando rodo o build pro celular, após selecionar o `select` o campo do outro index some.

Meu código:

```
resposta: string[] = [""];
saudacao: string = '';


<div>

      <ion-row>
        <div class="col-8">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-textarea name="resposta{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="resposta[pergunta.id]" value="{{resposta[pergunta.id]}}" placeholder="Resposta" clearInput></ion-textarea>
        </ion-item>
        </div>
      <div class="col-4">
          <a (click)="respondePergunta(i)"><ion-icon class="responderperguntaicon" name="ios-arrow-dropright-circle"></ion-icon></a>
          <a (click)="presentActionSheet()"><ion-icon id="maisopcoes" color="primary" name="more"></ion-icon></a>
      </div>
      </ion-row>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Resposta Automática</ion-label>
      <ion-select (ionChange)="adicionaArrayRespostaAutomatica($event, pergunta.id)">
        <ion-option value="Sim, temos no estoque ">Sim, temos no estoque</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="Não, não temos no momento ">Não, não temos no momento</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Inserção Rápida Sistema</ion-label>
      <ion-select (ionChange)="adicionaArrayInsercaoRapida($event, pergunta.id)">
        <ion-option value="{{saudacao}}">Saudação</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

  </div>
```

Minha função:

```
adicionaArrayRespostaAutomatica(event, index){
  if(this.resposta[index] == null){
    this.resposta[index] = '';
    this.resposta[index] = this.resposta[index] + ' ' + event;
  }else{
  this.resposta[index] = this.resposta[index] + ' ' + event;
  }
}

adicionaArrayInsercaoRapida(event,index){
  if(this.resposta[index] == null){
    this.resposta[index] = '';
    this.resposta[index] = this.resposta[index] + ' ' + event;
  }else{
  this.resposta[index] = event + this.resposta[index];
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Tive o mesmo problema e resolvi tirando o campo value com string vazia (value="") dos inputs e textarea. Observei que na sua 1ª linha tem string vazia.

```
resposta: string[] = [""];
```

Isso faz com que, após interagir com o select, o ionic deixe o value com esse valor inicial da variável resposta. Enfim tenta tirar o value do textarea. Funcionou pra mim.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).